# How can I connect a blu-ray player to a VGA screen?

Tags: display, vga, blu-ray, components

Basically, I have a blu-ray player that I wanted to be connected to a projector and a monitor screen at the same time, so I got a component splitter and a component to VGA cable. The splitter works fine but the component to VGA adapter doesn't show anything on the monitor screen; is like if nothing is connected to it. I already change monitors but 3 monitors do the same. Anyone have any idea why this is happening or how can I connect the monitor and the projector to the blu-ray?

Comment: Do you have a spare HD screen? Your older monitors may not have the resolution that your blu ray player is outputting. What is the model of the blu-ray? What is the model number of your display?

Comment: no i don't, but the monitor that I am using is a dell i e190 is like 2 years old, the blu-ray is sony-bdp-s350-frontpanel blu ray. so you think i should change the resolution on the monitor?

Comment: what resolution is the dell e190 set to?

Comment: well honestly i am not sure how to check...

Answer (score 0):

Use the component to VGA adapter on something else to make sure it's not defective (and make sure the things you are testing on work). I think you may need a spceical adapter for the blu ray, one that's HD capable, perhaps [this](http://www.datapro.net/products/hdtv-component-to-vga-converter.html).

Comment: wow this looks really cool the one i do have is straight component  to VGA but let me check on the other devices to make sure the adapter is working